# Write text on top of image using canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a canvas with an image and write it using fillText.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("UsedCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var image = new Image();
image.src = img;
image.onload = function() {
  ctx.font = "20px Georgia";
  ctx.fillText("Hello World!", 10, 50);
}
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.7);
console.log(dataURL);
```

```html
<canvas id="UsedCanvas"></canvas>
```

It works perfectly when viewing on canvas, but when I take the url (dataURL) and put it in the browser the text does not appear

Comment: The onload callback is asynchronous. Try calling the `canvas.toDataURL` at the bottom of the onload callback.

Comment: @JacobPenney thank you! Now it`s working